# How to run IE7 and IE8 on the same pc?

Tags: internet-explorer, ie8-compatibility-mode, ie8-browser-mode

I would like to check screen of my website on IE7 and IE8.

I have try to search on many website and I found IETester program follow [this website](http://forums.techarena.in/customize-desktop/1096599.htm). But it's not work for my website.

So, how do I use other programs or other solution to run IE7 and IE8 on the same PC?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I test my webpage in different IE versions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921205/how-can-i-test-my-webpage-in-different-ie-versions)

Comment: This is a dupe of: 1921205, 3782541, 693112, 574463, and many others.  Please search before asking.

Answer (score 8):

Use a virtual machine and maintain a separate installation of Windows in it.

Microsoft provide [images for this purpose](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF).

Comment: Those images expire after 3 months or so.  That particular link points to some images that just expired (October 1, 2010).

Answer (score 4):

You may want to try out the Expression Web SuperPreview, which is a free download from Microsoft and allows comparison of sites between IE6, 7 and 8.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=8e6ac106-525d-45d0-84db-dccff3fae677

A tutorial on how to use it can be found here:
http://any-expression.com/expression-web/v3-tutorials/superpreview.html

Comment: It's worth pointing out that SP compares sites *visually*, but does not run any javascript. It's basically an image comparison with some metadata for the elements' bounding boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the Virtual Machine answer, if you have Windows 7, you can use the XP Mode to run IE7.

[Using Windows 7’s “XP Mode” to run IE 6, IE 7 and IE8 side-by-side](http://blog.dotsmart.net/2009/06/24/using-windows-7s-xp-mode-to-run-ie-6-and-ie-7-side-by-side/)

Comment: As long as you have Windows 7 Professional or Ultimate. If you have Home, it's still possible to run Virtual PC 2007 (although Win 7 Home is not in the list of compatible operating systems.)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try IE Collection, which allows you to install lots of different versions of IE in parallel and is available [here](http://utilu.com/IECollection).

Also, creating virtual machines can be a good idea if you want to set up specific scenarios.  If you do this, remember to turn off auto-update on the VMs, or you might find that your IE6 VM has upgraded itself to IE8.